# Can I convert a varchar in number with format() function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting

Is there any possibility to convert a varchar in number with `format()` function?

for example if I want to convert number in varchar with `format()` function I write this code:

```
format(555, '0')
```

Comment: can you give samples on what you are talking? what do you mean by *varchar in anumber*?

Comment: for exemple I have a varchar '123' I want to convert in number 123, but if is posible with format() sql function

Comment: If you mean the new SQL Server 2012 [`FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function then **No**, the format argument part of it must be `nvarchar` for formatting options, like string formatting in C# for example, see the previous link for more info. But what do you want that number to looks like? What format do you to convert to? Currency or what?

Comment: what do you use `CAST` like `SELECT CASE('123' AS INT)`

Comment: You can also use Convert()

Comment: I know about cast and convert, but the problem is that I want my query to work for access and sql-Server concomitant and I know that format() works for both, if you have a more good Idee to work for both will be better

Comment: I thing this is not posible

Comment: MS Access/VBA format() produces string (nvarchar) either. You cannot use same formatting (and/or conversion) functions for Access and SQL anyway; you should handle formatting (and/or value conversion) somewhere in client code.